# Open files in emacs by filename instead of complete path

Tags: directory, emacs, filenames

Assume I have a bunch of directories and can guarantee that no two directories have a common filename (i.e. if `foo/bar` exists, then `bar` doesn't exist in any of the other directories). How can I setup emacs such that, given a hard-coded list in `.emacs` of the directories to search, I can tell it to open `bar` and it figures out that it's in `foo` rather than me needing to tell it `foo/bar` every time? It'd be even better if it handled name collisions somehow (e.g. a list of possible matches), but that's not mandatory as I'm certain in this case the directories have no filenames in common

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I write this, I discover [`ifind-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ifind-mode.el), which looks spot on.

```
(setq workspace-dir "/path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2")
(require 'ifind-mode)
;; maybe change `ifind-command' as well
```

Then type `M-x ifind-mode` to find a file in the specified directories (and subdirectories by default), with nifty completion.

---

What I usually do is `e **/bar` from zsh (where `e` is an alias for `emacsclient`). But that's disruptive if you're in Emacs already. Also, if there's a specific file I edit often, I leave it open (and I save my session).

Out of the box, you can run `M-x find-dired` and specify arguments to `find`. But that's clumsy, at least for the case when you have a single match. [`ifind`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ifind.el) makes this less clumsy.

[`ido`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) has a bunch of features that may be useful, especially [Use ido to find any file from the project](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings#toc12).

Comment: That looks very handy

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered [filecache](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/FileNameCache), which is perfect for my purposes. There are several functions of the form `file-cache-add-directory-X` to add files to the cache, and then in the middle of typing a filename in `find-file` you can hit <kbd>C-Tab</kbd> to autocomplete the path using the cache (hitting it multiple times cycles through matches)

The EmacsWiki post includes functions to save/restore the cache. I wrote a cron job to generate the cache file automatically every night; the file looks like this:

```
(("filename" "/path/to/that/file/") ("other filename" "/different/path/"))
```

Then I automatically load from the cache when emacs starts using the function mentioned on EmacsWiki:

```
(require 'filecache)
(defun file-cache-read-cache-from-file (file)
  "Clear `file-cache-alist' and read cache from FILE.
The file cache can be saved to a file using
`file-cache-save-cache-to-file'."
  (interactive "fFile: ")
  (file-cache-clear-cache)
  (let ((buf (find-file-noselect file)))
    (setq file-cache-alist (read buf))
    (kill-buffer buf)))

(file-cache-read-cache-from-file "~/.file-cache")
```

Answer (score 0):

There're couple of alternatives, e.g: recentf-mode and ido-find-file from [ido](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThing) package.